# how to convert tensor dtype float32_ref to dtype float32?

Tags: tensorflow

```
word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=_word_embeddings,ids=self.word_ids)
word_embeddings_modify = tf.scatter_nd_update(word_embeddings, self.error_word, sum_all)

Error:
Tensor conversion requested dtype float32_ref for Tensor with dtype float32
```

From the error it seems `word_embeddings` in function `scatter_nd_update` actual `dtype` is `tf.float_32`, but `scatter_nd_update` should accepted `word_embeddings dtype tf.float_32_ref`.

How can i change `word_embeddings's` `dtype` from `tf.float_32` to `tf.float_32_ref` before using `tf.scatter_nd_update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tf.Variable()` to convert dtype  directly. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

_word_embeddings = tf.get_variable(name='embedding',shape=[30, 5])

word_ids = [3,6,23]
word_embeddings = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(params=_word_embeddings,ids=word_ids)

error_word = [[1]]
sum_all = [[0,0,0,0,0]]
word_embeddings_modify = tf.scatter_nd_update(tf.Variable(word_embeddings), error_word, sum_all)

with tf.Session()as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(word_embeddings))
    print(sess.run(word_embeddings_modify))
[[ 0.08698401 -0.15590087  0.00285593 -0.13804913 -0.12418613]
 [-0.25748074  0.32121882 -0.390212    0.24590132  0.3976703 ]
 [-0.3023583   0.00366881 -0.05178839 -0.20865369  0.2887713 ]]
[[ 0.08698401 -0.15590087  0.00285593 -0.13804913 -0.12418613]
 [ 0.          0.          0.          0.          0.        ]
 [-0.3023583   0.00366881 -0.05178839 -0.20865369  0.2887713 ]]
```

It's strange why you update word embedding results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :)